# React router: component not updating on url search param change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a `React` application that uses `URL search params`. Depending on the value of the `search parameter v`, the component is supposed to show different content.

A possible `URL` might look like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/hello?v=12345
```

Once the `v query parameter` changes in the `URL`, I would like my component to update.

```
http://localhost:3000/hello?v=6789
```

I'm using using `react-router` in my App component to display the different components depending on the route. The `App` component is wrapped into a `BrowserRouter` component.

```
render() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/hello" component={Hello}></Route>
      <Route path="/" component={Home}></Route>
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

If a user clicks on something and the `URL search param v` changes, I would like the component to display different content. Currently, the `URL search param` does change, but the component doesn't render again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @forJ correctly pointed out, the main idea is to make the component re render once the `URL` parameters change. I achieved it like so:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/hello" render={() => (<Hello key={this.props.location.key}/>)}></Route>
      <Route path="/" component={Home}></Route>
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

`this.props.location.key` changes every time the `URL` changes (also if the query params change). So if you pass it as props to the component, then the component re renders on `URL` param changes, even though the `base URL` (the `URL` without the `URL` params) hasn't changed.

I also had to use the `withRouter` higher order component to make it work.

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Hello));
```

Comment: The `withRouter` is critical here if you are using redux.

Comment: Using "key" will cause a full unmounting and remounting of the component so consider the negative performance implications. https://medium.com/@albertogasparin/forcing-state-reset-on-a-react-component-by-using-the-key-prop-14b36cd7448e

Comment: I have no words to thank you. This Answer saved my week. Thanks for such a great solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you use useEffect hook make sure to have `[props.match.params]` instead of empty array `[]`

```
useEffect(() => {

        (async () => {
            // Fetch your data
        })();
    }, [props.match.params]) // <-- By this it will get called when URL changes
```

of course for class components `this.props.match.params`

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided enough information so I cannot be 100% sure where you are going wrong but I can see 1 problem right now in your code. First, you have to let the router know that you will be using parameters. So for example below code

```
render() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/hello/:yourParam" component={Hello}></Route> // you need the colon here
      <Route path="/" component={Home}></Route>
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

The above will tell the route that parameter called `yourParam` will be accessible from the `URL`

Then it has to be accessed in your component and put into render function somehow (use it to retrieve data from database to render data, just render params directly, etc).

For example below

```
render(){
    <div>
        {this.props.match.params.yourParam}
    </div>
}
```

This way, your component will re-render everytime there is param change.

EDIT

Since you want to use query instead of parameter, you would have to retrieve it by going. `this.props.match.query.v`. You would still have to make sure that variable is rendered depending on query change

Comment: If I do '/hello/:yourParam', then my url looks like localhost:3000/hello/123, but I want it to use URL search parameters so that the URL looks like localhost:3000/hello?v=123

Comment: @slashburn. Sorry my bad. Then you would just have to check that you are retrieving the query from the class by going `this.props.match.query.v` and make sure render function re-runs on change of that value

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks @forJ for pointing me into the right direction